# Unable to retrieve data on using .htaccess

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I am using follwing .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ topics.php?cat=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$ topics.php?cat=$1 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /topics.php?cat=$1&bsid=$2 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /topics.php?cat=$1&bsid=$2 
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
```

I have a folder or directory called images and there are files under it but on using this htacces code the files from images directory are nit retrieved when i directle go to acess like http://appricart.com/images/ajax-loading.gif i get empty page.
Help Regarding this ..Tnxx

Comment: That is because you are rewriting everything to topics.php. You need to include something to ignore directories and files.

Comment: how to do that? can u give me an example??

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible solution and I'd reccomend you not set up individual redirects on .htaccess but I think it's what you asked for. You have to check to see if the file exists before rewriting it.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ topics.php?cat=$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/%2 !-f
RewriteRule ^ /topics.php?cat=%1&bsid=%2  [L]
```

Try replacing your whole rewrite code into this. I've replaced some redundant stuff with just one rewrite on both parts.

For a cleaner solution look into [url routing](https://www.google.com/search?q=url+routing).

**Edit:** Try anunbhava's code, I think it should work.

Comment: this your code showig total erro..i m trying to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You should skip file/directories from this rewrite code.

Use this code:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# skip file and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ topics.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ topics.php?cat=$1&bsid=$2 [L,QSA]
```